# How do I access objects set in session scope using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using spring and making an AJAX call in the front end. On the server side I am setting an object into the session. Now I want to access the object in the call back function. How do I access that object.

Here , on click of a menu item a make an AJAX call

```
  $(function() {        
    $('#menu li').click(function(){ 
         var eventIDValue = $(this).attr('value');
         $.post('getScheduler' , 
                 {
                eventID : eventIDValue,
            } , function(data) {
                //WHAT DO I WRITE HERE TO ACCESS A SESSION OBJECT OR                                                                                
            });     
    });
  });
```

Comment: Well... your server needs to return that data in order for the client to access it. What is your sever responding with?

Answer (score 0):

Just get the session object value and include it in the response stream.
The callback function will get the http response object.

Here you have an ASP.NET Example:

Server side:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Write(Session["mySession"].toString());
Response.End();
```

Client side:

```
 success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
```

data object will only have your session value because you cleared the response before writing the value.

Comment: On the server side i am setting the attribute this way session.setAttribute("event", eventList.get(0)); and i want to access "event"